# In simple terms, is the permittivity of free space the polarizability of a vacuum?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, polarization

I'm having a hard time understanding the permittivity of free space in my own words. Wikipedia defines the permittivity of free space as "the value of the absolute dielectric permittivity of classical vacuum." and it defines the absolute dielectric permittivity as "a measure of the electric polarizability of a dielectric". So would that mean that the permittivity of free space is the polarizability  of a vacuum? If not, could someone please explain it in simple terms.

(I need to give a simple definition in a lab report and I want to understand it fully in my own words to avoid any possible plagarism.)

Comment: Related: [What is the physical meaning of $\epsilon_0$?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/567411/what-is-the-physical-meaning-of-epsilon-0) and [Why does the vacuum even have permeability and permittivity?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/440007/why-does-the-vacuum-even-have-permeability-and-permittivity)

Comment: @G.Smith Thanks so much, those really helped! I had looked around for other questions but I hadn't seen either of those. I understand now.